# How to use a named range as an output for IF statement in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a simple IF statement in excel which uses a named range which is a range of countries, i.e. NOT numbers however I am getting the "#VALUE" in the cell with the warning "A value used in this formula is of the wrong data type"

Formula in Cell:  `=IF($F$5="All", Countries, F5)`

where "Countries" is my named range

Can this be done?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your formula **IS** returning an array of the values of the Named Range. You can see them individually by placing your cursor in the Formula Bar, and then hitting `F9`; you can return them individually by using the `INDEX` function, or you can enter the formula as an array over multiple cells of the same size and shape as `Countries`.  In the latest versions of Excel, the results would automatically SPILL over into the adjacent cells, if there is room.

Comment: Thank you I can see the values now!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Are you looking for something like that?

```
=IF(F5="All",TEXTJOIN(", ",,Countries),F5)
```

`Countries` range is specified in cells `A1:A5`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a good trick for me to know but in this instance I will be passing the list into sql so I think without the commas is best and think I have somethign working now!